# How can I replace a string in a specific line and field in multiple files using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have a file with this content

```
2:33:4:F:T:Y
1:10:0:A:B:C:D:E:F:G:
```

how to change `F` in second line to `R` for multiple files using `sed`?

The desired output would be:

```
2:33:4:F:T:Y
1:10:0:A:B:C:D:E:R:G:
```

Edit:

the change should be only in second line of every file, the fields delimited by : so i need the 9th field to be changed, and ignore if the filed have anything but only F.

Comment: can you show what you have tried yet?

Comment: i tried gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/F/,"R",$9); print}' file, but newer version is not installed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Does this replacement need to be ONLY on the 2nd line of each file and ONLY if the ENTIRE value of the 9th field is `F`? Should all other lines be ignored? Are fields defined by `:`? Can the field be `FR` or anything else that includes `F`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` :

Replace every `2nd` line on each file and also on `9th field` F to R

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} FNR==2{ sub(/^F$/,"R",$9); }1' file1 file2 
2:33:4:F:T:Y
1:10:0:A:B:C:D:E:R:G:
2:33:4:F:T:Y
1:10:0:A:B:C:D:E:R:G:
```

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar thanks for the answer, the awk is more accurate, saved my day :)

Comment: @Mavia Pleasure . Have a great day ...

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
$ awk -F: -vOFS=: '($9=="F" && NR==2){$9="R"}1' file
2:33:4:F:T:Y
1:10:0:A:B:C:D:E:R:G:
```

For many files, do:

```
for file in *; do 
    awk -F: -vOFS=: '($9=="F" && NR==2){$9="R"}1' "$file" > newfile &&
    mv newfile "$file"
done
```

Or, with newer versions of GNU awk:

```
gawk -iinplace -F: -vOFS=: '($9=="F" && FNR==2){$9="R"}1' file.*
```

Comment: Hi Terdon, would you mind adding a space between the flags and the arguments, such as `-F :` and `-v OFS=:` so they conform to the standards? (Please correct me in case I'm wrong.)

Comment: @Quasímodo what standards? I've personally always written them like this and I don't know of any standard that requires a space. You may well be right, I just don't know of one and I admit I prefer this syntax :)

Comment: Oops, sorry for not being complete :S I meant [the awk POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). In the synopsis the `-F` and `-v` are followed by space.